# Plot not rendering with Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app that displays a ggplot using a built in data set from the library `macheish`. However, when I run my code, I do not get any errors, but my ggplot does not display. Here is what I see:

[No display of ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJZKA.png)

Ideally I would like to see something like this

[With display of ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecyXo.png)

Here is my code:

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(input = "datasets", label = "Choose a Dataset:",
                   choices = c("whately_2015", "orchard_2015"))),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("ggPlot"))
    )
  )
)
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(macleish)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$datasets,
           "whately_2015" = whately_2015,
           "orchard_2015" = orchard_2015)

    output$ggPlot <- renderPlot({
      p <- ggplot(data = input$datasets, aes(y = temperature, x = when)) + 
        geom_line(color = "darkgray") +
        geom_smooth() +
        xlab("Time") +
        ylab("Temperature (in F)") +
        ggtitle("Weather Data in 2015") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
      print(p)

    })
  })
})
```

Could someone help me out by pointing out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You should close and call `reactive` correctly. See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) on how `reactive` and `renderPlot` work. However, after I did that I get the 2nd plot but the first plot through an error 'object 'when' not found'

Comment: @A.Suliman I misspelled whately_2015, I've edit my post with the correct spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correction you need -

```
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$datasets,
           "whatley_2015" = whately_2015,
           "orchard_2015" = orchard_2015)
  })

    output$ggPlot <- renderPlot({
      p <- ggplot(data = datasetInput(), aes(y = temperature, x = when)) + 
        geom_line(color = "darkgray") +
        geom_smooth() +
        xlab("Time") +
        ylab("Temperature (in F)") +
        ggtitle("Weather Data in 2015") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
      print(p)    
    })
```